# Jenkins perforce plugin: can I get it to do full sync if key files are missing?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are using the Jenkins perforce plugin reasonably successfully in a semi-continuous integration setup. The "reasonably" in generally because our builds are slow, but this is not related to Jenkins and more to do with our own code.

One of the main problems we have is that if files have been deleted outside the builds - e.g. if we are low on diskspace and somebody "prunes" the builds on the build machines - the p4 plugin cannot directly handle that. In the mode we run it (without full-sync flag) it assumes that files sync'd on the previous run are still there.

This is covered under "quirks" on the plugin page - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Perforce+Plugin - which suggests that you do a "One Time Force Sync" to get the workspace back to normal. However, we usually have a couple of build machines with each config for a bit of redundancy. In that case, the machine you run next is not always the same as the one that had the problem. This also makes it tricky adding new machines to the pool.

I wondered if somebody had a better solution. E.g. if certain key files are missing (indicative of a build being wiped) it does a forced sync anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it took me a while but I eventually twigged an approach that works at least in our setup. Pretty well near the top of the job we check for the existence of a particular file. If this does not exist, we assume the workspace has been wiped (if it does exist, we assume is OK). If it has been wiped, we do the equivalent of a "Remove From Client" of all the files. Actually we modify a few files during the build, so I've added a revert in for good measure. Not sure if it is generally required - I suspect not - but should do no harm.

On a PC this means adding the following to the first build step:

```
IF NOT EXIST //%P4CLIENT%/sdk/ChangeLog.txt (
    REM Remove from client. Throw away any files being modified
    p4 revert %WORKSPACE%/...
    p4 sync %WORKSPACE%/...#none > nul
)
```

On a Mac (and Linux boxes I assume):

```
if ! [ -e //%P4CLIENT%/sdk/ChangeLog.txt ]
then
    # Remove from client. Throw away any files being modified
    p4 revert $WORKSPACE/...
    p4 sync $WORKSPACE/...#none > /dev/null
fi
```

sdk/ChangeLog.txt is the file we assume marks a valid installation. What this effectively does is to reset the environment so that the next sync is the equivalent of a forced sync.